# MVC manage session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using an MVC app to manage authentication. The issue I have is with chrome because it never actually kills the session because it runs in the background after it closes by default. I do not want to enforce all the end users to change this setting because then it will kill hangouts etc.. So I am wondering if I can use any standard web.config setting to handle this or do I need to make an ajax polling interval to keep updating the cookie expiration?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: I want to know, with MVC how can I automatically kill a users session when the browser is closed. ie log the user out when they close their browser

Comment: Are you managing cookies yourself? If so, you'll need to set the expiration of the cookie to `DateTime.MinValue` which effectively creates a session cookie. This means when the browser is closed the cookie is removed, even if Chrome still has tasks running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET session consists of 2 components the client-side http session cookie and the server's session storage provider. Suppose user has SessionId 1. If you delete session 1 from the server, the user returns and a new session is created with SessionId 1. If the user deletes the session cookie, the server keeps running session 1.

What you're asking for is generally **not possible**. There's no way you can force a user to send a request to your server when they are exiting your site or the browser. There is the javascript `beforeUnload` event which in some situations would allow you to send a request to `/sign-off` in some situations. The obvious limiter is no network access = no message.

The standard resolution for orphaned sessions is for session scavenging policy to clean them up. Some developers choose to use persistent storage to eliminate scavenging altogether such that a shopping cart would never disappear.

The only reasonable solution (which is still overkill) that would reach your goals. You use SingalR for a persistent connection of the user to the server and you ping them from the server. If the connection fails to respond you abandon the session. This will be a fragile process and if you don't make very very sure the user is disconnected you will have lots of support calls from users wondering why they are continuously logged out while browsing your site on cell phone.